# Unable to render a component conditionally

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render a component conditionally based on parent's state. But I am unable to do that.

In my current code, I am able to see component after "todos.length>0" but when I start to type in any text fields.

My parent component:

```
function App() {
  const [title,setTitle] = React.useState("")
  const [desc, setDesc] = React.useState("")
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([])

  const titleChange = (e) => {
           const value=e.target.value;
           setTitle(value)
  }

  const descChange = (e) => {
           const value=e.target.value;
           setDesc(value)
  }

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setTitle("");
    setDesc("")
  }

  const handleAdd = () => {
    const newTodos = todos;
    newTodos.push({
      title:title,
      description: desc
    });
    setTodos(newTodos)
  }

  return (
    <div >
      <label>Enter Title</label>
      <TextField onChange={(e) => titleChange(e)} value={title} />
      <label>Description</label>
      <TextArea onChange={(e) => descChange(e)} value = {desc}/>
      <Button onClick={handleCancel}>Cancel</Button>
      <Button onClick={handleAdd}>ADD</Button>
<div>
      {todos.length && <TodoList todos={todos} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My child component:

```
export default function TodoList (props){

    React.useEffect(() => {
      console.log("mounted")
    })

    return (
        <div>
        {console.log(props)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Even, I tried using ternary operator like this,

```
todos.length ? <TodoList todos={todos} /> : null
```

Comment: Don't mutate state: `const newTodos = todos;`

Comment: Also read [list and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay you are missing something, in your handleAdd function you are just pushing to the same array, this way React will have the same reference of the previous array so it will bail out of the state update, you should create a new array from the existing one
Change your handleAdd as this

```
const handleAdd = () => {
const newTodos = [ ...todos];
newTodos.push({
  title:title,
  description: desc
});
setTodos(newTodos)
```

}

This way React will update the todos state, and change

```
{todos.length && <TodoList todos={todos} />}
```

to

```
{todos.length > 0 && <TodoList todos={todos} />}
```

one more thing in your child component instead of logging, get the size of array in div

```
<div>
    {props.todos.length}
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display to do list if some tasks in it

```
todos.length > 0 ? <TodoList todos={todos} /> : null
```

Or you can do in this way

```
{ todos.lenght > 0 && <TodoList todos={todos} /> }
```

`{ true && expression }` returns `expression`
`{ false && expression }` return `false`

Answer (score 0):

Don't mutate state.

Just correct your `handleAdd` function.

```
  const handleAdd = () => {
    setTodos([...todos, {title: title, description: desc }])
  };
```

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

When `component` renders  very first time `todos length` will always `0`. So `{todos.length &&` condition becomes `false`.

*you should use something like that to avoid this issue :*

```
{todos.length >0  && <TodoList todos={todos} />}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your handleAdd function should look like this:

```
const handleAdd = () => {
   setTodos(todos => [...todos, { title: title, description: desc }]);
};
```

If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Answer (score -1):

This may not make a difference, but you don't need to create a function as value for onChange in your TextField components. onChange is going to pass event to your function unless your TextField component isn't handling that properly. In other words, the usage of the TextField components should look like this...

```
<TextField onChange={titleChange} value={title} />
```

Your TextField component itself should be doing something like this...

```
function TextField({onChange}) {
    function handleChange(event) {
        // Pass the event as an argument into the onChange prop
        onChange(event) 
    }

    return <input onChange={handleChange} />
}
```

If your TextField component is a third party component, they do at least pass a value back as an argument so check that.

Another possibility is you are actually mutating todos in the handleAdd function. If you want to insure todos isn't mutated you can use the ES6 way of adding values to an array...

```
function handleAdd() {
  setTodos([
    ...todos, 
    {
      title: title,
      description: desc
    }
  ])
}
```

If none of that helps console.log your todos state in the parent component and see if it is changing.